# Loading.tsx in Next13 with NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

i have a problem with the new loading indicator and nginx. The problem is that nginx is not displaying my loading animation, but waiting for next to serve the page. So you can understand me better here are two urls:

Here is the url directly to the next server running on a docker container: http://81.169.168.154:3000/jam/gmtk-2019. This way the loading animation gets displayed as expected.

But using the nginx server: https://jamalyzer.com/jam/gmtk-2019 the animations doesn't get displayed.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server{

    server_name jamalyzer.com www.jamalyzer.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by disabling the proxy_buffering in the config

```
server{

    server_name jamalyzer.com www.jamalyzer.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```